# alguien me orienta con este error de javascript pls :(

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert

por alguna razón cuando le pongo `$(document).ready(function(){` no me funcionan las ventanas, he hecho un monton de cosas, ver videos y cambiar el codigo ya sea `$(function(){` o hacerlo desde mi codigo html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien sabe por qué pasa esto? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? :(

Comment: Prueba document.addEventListener('load',()=>{alert('hola')});

Comment: ¿La consola te lanza algún error? A lo mejor tienes puesto tu script antes de importar la librería jquery

Comment: Hola sofia, es muy recomendable que cada que puedas agregues código y evites al máximo ponerlo en imágenes. Esto también aplica para los errores que puedas obtener. Te invito a que pases por [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del centro de ayuda y si tienes dudas a la hora de editar y redactar puedes leer la [Ayuda de edición de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 4):

El código funciona perfecto... Tiene que estar entre las etiquetas `<script></script>`, de esta manera:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hola")
  });
</script>
```

Código funcionando:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("hola")
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```